# AngularJS how to dynamically update part of scope with variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to update one of my scope properties dynamically

I have a scope property that looks like this

```
$scope.content.portrait_description.data
```

But the portrait_description needs to be able to be replaced by a variable called name, like this

```
$scope.content.name.data
```

and in this case, the name variable is equal to portrait_description.

When I try this it doesn't work, i've also tried `$scope.content. + name + .data` and `$scope.content.{{name}}.data` but neither work. Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
$scope.content[name].data
```

Comment: @MitchGlenn -- You didnt use the code above, you have a `.` after `content` - remove it. It's NOT: `$scope.content.[name].data = data.data;`, it's : `$scope.content[name].data`

Comment: I just realized that! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Objects in Javascript works like array or dictionaries do this instead:

```
var varname = "somePropertyName";
$scope.content[varname].data = "hello";
```